# Codename One Android build upload issue - calendar button disconfigured

Tags: css, codenameone, stylesheet

I very much like working with CN1. Unfortunately, last week an issue appeared, that has not existed before and I can't figure out a workaround.

When I upload my app up to the build server, the interface of my application gets strangely disconfigured. This happens during the upload process and affects both the uploaded app, as well as the app that is on my machine.

The app contains a calendar, a table, buttons and labels, but only the calendar is affected. There are several day buttons that are styled through css, but during the upload the day buttons lose their format, and so does the text of the remaining buttons.

The upload of the same app with identical configuration has worked seemlessly in the past and the problem with disconfiguration only appeared over the last days.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
   @Override
   protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentYear, int currentMonth, int day  ) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
        //List <Integer>list = new List<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(12);
        list.add(13);
        list.add(14);
        list.add(21);


        for (int day_Number : list) {

            if (day_Number == day) {

                dayButton.setText("" + day);
                //dayButton.setUIID("mycalenderday");

            }

        }

        }

    };
```

[image][image]

Comment: What UIIDs specifically did you style in CSS?

Comment: Quite a few, Diamond. I have added the entire css code above ....  Interestingly, the whole thing has worked in the past, but only the last versions show this behavior.

Comment: I noticed some spelling mistakes in the UIID `Calendar` spelled as `Calender`, Is this intentional?

Comment: Diamond, thanks for pointing this out, very subtle ... totally accidental, though .. I changed the spelling but it didn't affect the result. When being uploaded,  both the app that are on the server and the one on my machine get disconfigured. Instead of several selected day buttons, I see only one and with the wrong background and text formatting ...

Comment: I'm assuming that when you say "upload" you mean build? This fetches the latest libs version which means a change to calendar over the past week or two triggered this regression. Looking at the history you can see the changes here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commits/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Calendar.java The one thing I see that might be a mistake is that you used `CalendarDaySelected` where you might have intended `CalendarSelectedDay`

Comment: I have been trying around and protected void updateButtonDayDate(Component dayButton, int currentYear, int currentMonth, int day  ) seems to work ..... so the issue seems to be solved ...